# Correlating input files to output files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MR streaming job. My code is in C++. Its a mapper only job, with no reducer. Input to the the job is a directory containing three files. Job creates 3 mappers. Each mapper processes one input file and produces one output file in different format.

Input files are like:

```
MyDir/file1
MyDir/file2
MyDir/file3
```

Output file are like:

```
MyDir/Output/part-00000
MyDir/Output/part-00001
MyDir/Output/part-00002
```

I want to correlate input files to output files. For example, input file `MyDir/file1` may correspond to output file `MyDir/Output/part-00002`, i.e. mapper that processed input file `MyDir/file1` may have produced output file `MyDir/Output/part-00002`.

I want to know this relationship, i.e., which input file corresponds to which output file. Is there a simple way to know this?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is it to have the i/p and the o/p file names of the Job the same. Get the input file name ([map.input.file](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html) environment property) which the mapper is processing and then us it in the [MultipleOutputFormat#generateFileNameForKeyValue](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html#generateFileNameForKeyValue%28K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

With how Hadoop is designed, the only relationship that you can rely on, without you expressly naming the output files as per the other answer, is that the number of output files corresponds to the number of final tasks being run, usually reducers (mappers in your case, since you're not running any reducers).

If Hadoop later decides to run more mappers/reducers instead of just 3 (larger input files, more nodes available), you'll get a different number of output files.

Comment: I don't get it - can you be a bit more clear with an example? `If Hadoop later decides to run more mappers/reducers` - Hadoop doesn't decide on the fly the # of mappers/reducers. The # of mappers equals the number of input splits and the user specifies the # of reducers.

Comment: I've assumed that over time, you will be running the same Hadoop job over different input files, with different sizes.  A common use case is a daily analysis of log files captured from the previous day.

Comment: I can make sure that each file is processed by one mapper by avoiding split or using .gz file.